# SVN on Linux Mandriva - access to remote repository from the Windows- web- browser

Tags: linux, svn, redmine

I want access the repository from the web- browser, do so -

Access via WebDAV.

passwd file:

```
    ...
    [users]
    harry = harryssecret
    sally = sallyssecret
```

...

```
<VirtualHost remote-ip:81>
    <Location /svn>
      DAV svn
      SVNPath /home/svn
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "...."
      AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
      Require valid-user
     </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache:

```
ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Request from Windows host:

```
http: //remote-ip:81/svn/test
```

Get the response:

[image]

Enter `harry` and `harryssecret`, but I get:

> 401:Authorization Required

*This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

**All**, starting from "not reading [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html)"

AuthUserFile require standard Apache's passwd file, <strike>path-based ACLs (which you *tried* to write into passwd) require additional module in LoadModule and additional directive in `<Location>`</strike>, your passwd file from svn://-served repo for svnserve

Example from my live system (relevant parts)

https.conf

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile ...htpasswd
AuthzSVNAccessFile ...authz

Satisfy Any
Require valid-user
```

- Satisfy+Require for RO anonymous access to repos
- Require valid-user for auth. write-access
- AuthUserFile - flat userlist
- AuthzSVNAccessFile - path-based ACLs

htpasswd

```
lazybadger:$apr1$5tg...
```

(string with encoded username-pass per user)

authz

```
[/]
*=r

[Elgg-Russian:/]
@Coders=rw

[Elgg-TranslationRU:/]
@Translators=rw

[Hello:/]
lazybadger=rw
```

(groups, subtrees in SVN location, changed from default access-rights)